AMDGPU issue after upgrading from 22.04 to 24.04.1
An online upgrade via GUI went smmoth. After boot it seems to work fine except for the video. After suggestions from elsewhere I had downloaded a version of green_sardine_sdma.bin from 2021 but it still doesn't work.
For some reason, dmesg now gives:
Direct firmware load for amdgpu/green_sardine_asd.bin failed with error -2
Previously it failed with the same error but with green_sardine_sdma.bin.
2 questions:

Where can I get the appropriate bin?
Why does it now show asd instead of sdma?

Any suggestions greatly appreciated.
TIA,
Dave

Problem solved! Somehow the distribution upgrade hadn't completely been installed and I was still running the old kernel! Probably user error, but all's well now.
